# @AliasFor for interface with @Retention(RetentionPolicy.METHOD)?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger

So Im trying to create an alias for

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiResponses {
    ApiResponse[] value();
}
```

What I tried,

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface targetTest {
    @AliasFor(annotation = ApiResponses.class, attribute="value")
    ApiResponse[] value()
    default {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "test1"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "test2"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "test3"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "test4")
    };
}
```

This does not override the ApiResponses annotation when I use

```
@targetTest
doSomething()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried changing retention policy of @ApiResponses to @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) ?? coz Runtime retention policy demands the annotation available for reflection at runtime.

Comment: I cant because @ApiResponses is a third-party annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `@ApiResponses` on `TargetTest`

```
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiResponses {
    ApiResponse[] value() default {};
}

@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ApiResponses
public @interface TargetTest {
    @AliasFor(annotation = ApiResponses.class)
    ApiResponse[] value() default {...};
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but get the following message "The annotation @ApiResponses is disallowed for this location"

Comment: I see the code but lets assume that @ApiResponse is strictly targeted for Methods only

Comment: @katotedomoji It's my mistake. It should be `ANNOTATION_TYPE` not `TYPE`.